# Como enviar texto para a impressora com PHP e Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, impressão

Preciso imprimir um texto que nao esteja necessariamente contido no documento html em uma impressora instalada no cliente, preciso abrir aquela janela pra selecionar impressoras e etc e enviar a impressão.

// EDIT

No caso a impressão seria enviada pra uma impressora de etiquetas termicas zebra que utiliza linguagem EPL, logo não posso enviar o documento html para a impressão.

Comment: Sem abrir um documento fica difícil. A menos que você use o [PHP-GTK](http://www.php-gtk.com.br/), que teria que ficar do lado do cliente.

Comment: Hmn... dificil pois preciso imprimir em uma impressora zebra que utiliza linguagem epl, então a impressao do documento html não resolve meu problema ;s

Comment: @alleen94, tentou usar a extensão [printer](http://br1.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php) ?

Comment: @perdeu ha cara todo lugar que vi gente tentando usar isso ai o pessoal só reclama, muita dor de cabeça e pouco resultado

Comment: Se você sabe o formato do arquivo que a impressora lê não é só salvar o arquivo no spooler de impressão? O sistema vai ler aquilo e imprimir sozinho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não acho que isso seja possível como você quer.

PHP é uma linguagem que fica no servidor. Ela nunca conversa diretamente com o cliente; o único jeito de ela "dizer" alguma coisa ao cliente é por meio de uma interface (que costuma ser o Javascript e o Html). Portanto, a menos que a impressora esteja conectada ao servidor PHP, não imagino como você pode imprimir algo usando o PHP.

Um modo seria ter um servidor PHP instalado no cliente, que escute a uma URL (por exemplo, `/imprimir.php?nomeDoDocumento=(...)`), e, assim que essa URL fosse chamada, o próprio PHP chamaria a impressão. [Você pode usar isso como referência, se for o caso](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php). Note que, nesse caso, você sequer precisa usar o Javascript (mas pode usar, caso queira chamar essa URL via Ajax, por exemplo).

Caso você não tenha um servidor PHP no cliente (o que é bem provável), você não tem como imprimir algo que esteja fora de um documento. Mas você pode esconder o documento para que não seja exibido no navegador, apenas na impressão. Para isso você usa um `iframe` escondido, por exemplo.

Agora eu vou adaptar um pedaço [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16667377/1418103) do SO internacional.

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = urlOfFile;
iframe.style.display = "none";

var iFrameLoaded = function() {
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
};

if (iframe.attachEvent) // Internet Explorer
  iframe.attachEvent('onload', iFrameLoaded);
else if (iframe.addEventListener) // Outros navegadores modernos
  iframe.addEventListener('load', iFrameLoaded, false);
else // Outros navegadores
  iframe.onload = iFrameLoaded;

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Basta colocar o código acima no evento de um botão ou carregamento de página, por exemplo.

**UPDATE**: Pela sua edição na pergunta, imagino que nenhuma das duas soluções propostas por mim lhe servem. Então, vou dar mais uma.

Não conheço essa linguagem EPL, nem impressoras Zebra. Mas me surgiu uma curiosidade: não existe algum driver ou simulador desta impressora que seja capaz de gerar arquivos de imagem ou PDF?

Caso exista, você pode usá-lo para gerar um arquivo e enviar esse arquivo via PHP para o cliente, e assim ele poderá imprimí-lo normalmente.

**UPDATE 2**: Pelo visto, o que você está querendo fazer, desse jeito, realmente é impossível.

Mas não é impossível de outra forma. Você precisa de um meio para se comunicar com a impressora. O Javascript pode até não fazer isso, mas ele pode trabalhar com arquivos e ele pode se comunicar com outras aplicações através do AJAX.

Aqui vão meus dois centavos: Crie um mini-servidor standalone para os clientes. Uma aplicação desktop. Acho que é possível com o [PHP-GTK](http://www.php-gtk.com.br/), apesar de eu nunca tê-lo usado na prática. As versões mais novas do PHP vêm com um mini-servidor de desenvolvimento; apesar de não ser recomendado usá-lo em produção, deve ser suficiente para o que você quer alcançar.

Se me permite dar uma opinião, acho que você se daria bem criando um pacote em outra linguagem. Uma opção seria [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/) + [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/2x/) + [AppJS](http://appjs.com/). Com esses três você consegue criar um pacote para o cliente, e se quiser ser mais perfeccionista, pode até criar seu instalador. Outra opção seria [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/) + [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) + [Tar2RubyScript + RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/tar2rubyscript/). Você escolhe sua linguagem e plataforma, só dei exemplos. Você conhece seus clientes e assim deve saber suas preferências.

Uma vez que você tenha um pequeno servidor stand-alone, você pode fazer requisições a ele via [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Não vou me aprofundar nisso aqui, você pode fazer outra pergunta sobre como usar o AJAX ou esses mini-servidores.

Tenha em mente que fazer isso não será fácil. Mas é o jeito que eu imagino que você pode conseguir.

Comment: Então andré infelizmente não.. o unico modo que consigo imprimir atualmente é enviando via shell um comando tipo 
TYPE C:\ETIQUETA.TXT >>LPT1
enviando um txt com os comandos para a impressora, porem isso só funciona para a impressora instalada na com ou lpt, e se eu abro esse txt e tento imprimir não impressora ela não interpreta os codigos..

Comment: Aí já fica mais difícil. O único meio que eu vejo é tendo um servidor PHP no cliente, já que o servidor PHP pode usar o shell.

Comment: Então André mas no caso isso seria um serviço online e fica inviável cada cliente ter um servidor instalado local

Comment: Entendo. Mas todos os clientes possuem a impressora, certo?

Comment: Sim todos possuem, é pelo que andei vendo acho que sua solução será a melhor mesmo obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Para imprimir a página atual, cujo CSS não expclicitamente diga que certas partes não devem ser impressas, use o javascript `print`. [Documentação no MDN do print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print).

```
window.print();
```

Para controlar com CSS o que na página atual deve ser exibido, e o que não deve, faça o seguinte:

```
/* Tudo que estiver nesse código, será considerado apenas
 quando um documento HTML for exibido pra impressão */
@media print {

 /* ocultar */
 .imprimir-esconde {
   display: none;
  }
  /* Lembre-se que o que por para exibir aqui, por padrão 
    deveria ser ocultado caso você não queira que o texto 
    seja exibido por padrão */
  .imprimir-exibe {
   display: block;
  }
}
```

Quanto a parte de 'não imprimir algo que já está sendo visto', você tem duas opções.

1. Na página atual, ter um link para a página que tem o conteúdo para ser impresso e neça ter o `print`.
2. Ter o conteúdo a ser impressõ na atual, mas CSS esconder ele até que você use o comando imprimir.

### Imprimir sem usar Drivers nativos de impressão

Javascript também permite baixar o nível e fazer uma comunicação com [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets) e acessar direto a impressora, caso ela esteja acessível via IP e porta. Isso não é algo trivial, mas acessar direto um protocolo de rede não é algo trivial de qualquer forma e a questão que fez, se não usar drivers padrões instalados no computador do cliente, é complexa por natureza.

Na MDN tem uma introdução a como escrever uma aplicação que usa essa tecnologia https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: Então o problema é que preciso imprimir em uma impressora zebra utilizando linguagem epl

Comment: Bem, se o navegador não tem os drivers para imprimir a página, você terá que enviar o documento para um servidor (quer seja apenas o link, ou então o documento inteiro) e só então esse servidor imprimir o documento. Fazer isso tudo é um projeto inteiro. Se é isso que quer, vou marcar na minha resposta isso para que ela seja considerada certa.

Comment: então mas no caso esse servidor de impressão deve ter a impressora localmente não é ?

Comment: Ou isso, ou você deverá criar uma extensão para o navegador, e que essa extensão acesse um Driver. Ou então você pode baixar o nível e fazer uma comunicação com `WebSockets` e acessar direto a impressora, caso ela esteja acessível via IP e porta http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets

Answer (score 2):

Como já mencionado, não é possível usar Javascript para enviar comandos para a impressora, sendo necessário uma linguagem com acesso de mais baixo nível ao sistema operacional para executar a comunicação diretamente com a impressora.

Nesse cenário, algo que me veio à mente é a solução que algumas empresas usam: **Applets Java**. Eu não gosto muito de *applets*, mas parece ser o único meio de resolver problemas como esse além de criar componentes específicos para cada navegador.

Fiz uma breve [pesquisa no Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=applet%20java%20print%20zebra&oq=applet%20java%20print%20zebra&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2146j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) e o primeiro resultado foi um projeto de código livre chamado [jzebra](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/), que se propõe a fazer exatamente o que você precisa: comunicação com impressoras laser e postscript, além de ser *cross browser*. Então não seria necessário você gastar muito tempo aprendendo Java, apenas precisa estudar esta ou outra ferramenta.

Comment: Então andei dando uma olhada no jzebra mais ta dando muita zebra.. kk

Answer (score 1):

Estou passando pelo mesmo problema, PHP e impressão direta no cliente.
No meu caso eu resolvi utilizando a aplicação PHP Desktop, é um navegador (chromium) compilado para rodar um mini servidor php no cliente, com isso eu consegui fazer a impressão sem problemas gerando um arquivo TXT e enviando o arquivo para a impressora por comandos do sistema.

Se interessar eu te passo alguns links que tenho salvo em uma máquina virtual.

Comment: Altere seu post e coloque os links e métodos que usou! obrigado!

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/52289)

Comment: Stefânio, a gente responde aqui para os futuros visitantes também. Então pode adicionar tudo que achar legal para resolver o problema, pode ser que o autor da pergunta não se interesse, mas com certeza outros visitantes vão achar bom ;)

Comment: @DanielFalbel, `resolvi utilizando a aplicação PHP Desktop`, mesmo que seja pobre em detalhes, é uma tentativa de responder a pergunta. Não devemos votar para deletar nesses casos. Só quando é totalmente viagem ou spam ou vandalismo ou comentário alheio ou tentativa do AP de dar mais detalhes.... Tentar dar uma solução **é uma resposta**, pode fazer -1 se achar conveniente.

Comment: @brasofilo falha minha! sinal de que preciso prestar muito mais atenção nas análises!